# How to change date and time format from Arabic to English

Tags: kde, date

Hi I am using Kubuntu and my language system is english but when I am using date command the output result is arabic format like this   جمعه ۱۸ ژوئیه ۱۴، ساعت ۰۲:۳۴:۵۸ (IRDT)
what should I do to change this???

Answer (score 0):

You can Change the format from  **KDE System Settings > Locale > Languages**

[image]

Comment: I said my system languages is English but my date format is persian like I said

Comment: So it could be the country then. Cant you apply English (system wide) like in Ubuntu??

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the given solution, the developpers must include this in the Time and Date Settings directly. The easy way to live!